# character in apex:pagemessages is getting escaped

Tags: visualforce, error-messages

[image]I am trying to put custom error message using Apex:PageMessges. Message contains HTML tags so I have used option <<"apex:pageMessages escape="false" />>. One of my message is like:
 message = '<<"b>>Warning '+countMsg+': <<"/b>>'+msg;
where countMsg is counter and msg is messge. When it is getting displayed the character coming after warning is getting escaped / replaced by blank.

For e.g. if countMsg value is 1 then if msg string contains 1 it is being replaced by blank.

Comment: hey it is quite confusing because I can see that you are facing issue typing exact error message here so it would be great if you can update your question with screenshots.

Comment: like below screen shot count of message is one and it is replacing all 1s:

Comment: countMsg is controller property ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question, I figured out the issue. There was code which was trying to remove count value of warning messages when there is only one message. That code was replacing the characters appearing after warning from whole string.